# SWFUpload and WEBrick. Problems with upload (error: 2038)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, flash, webrick

My WEBrick log reads:

> WARN Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content length of the response or set response#chunked = true

I did some searching and found that that error could be because:

1. File size permitted by the server is less than the upload size.
2. Lack of free space on the server (Checked. There is enough)

Any help on the topic?

PS: I have tried thin too. No help there either. Or maybe I missed some option in the 'thin config' option.

Also, my log since the page request: if this helps: http://paste.pocoo.org/raw/580142/

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your Gemfile

```
gem "rack-raw-upload"
```

This supports the Ajax-Upload in rails.

Comment: Not working. Added the log entry to my main post, if that helps. Thanks!